# Multicolor SF Symbol in macOS 11 Big Sur

Tags: xcode, cocoa, interface-builder, nstoolbar, sf-symbols

I want to programmatically add to the toolbar the "star.fill" symbol in multicolor yellow mode.

I can do it via Xcode/IB properties.

[image]

But I don't understand how to do it programmatically, because `NSSymbolConfiguration - configurationPreferringMulticolor` is only added in macOS 12 Monterey and doesn't work in Big Sur.